# pstricks generates \pgfutil at protected\def\pgfmathprintnumber{% error

Tags: miktex, pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass{amsbook} 
\usepackage{pst-eucl} %wrapper for PSTRICKS
\let\clipbox\relax    %needed to overcome some incompatibility
\begin{document} ...
\end{document}
```

gives error **\pgfutil at protected\def\pgfmathprintnumber{%**

To avoid this problem, it has been suggested elsewhere that I place

```
\ifx\pgfkeysloaded\relax
     \else \ifdefined\@latexerr % format is latex
    >     \RequirePackage{pgffor} % pgffor depends on pgfkeys   
      \else % format is plaintex
    >     \input pgffor.tex   
      \fi 
\fi
```

in pstricks.tex.  However, I have no such file on my system.  Instead, using MikTex, I find pst-eucl.sty and pstricks.sty, and inserting this code here or there in either of them has no effect.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! You've asked a question about why you can't make a possible solution to your problem work, but I'm unclear on what your actual problem is. Could you perhaps edit your question so that we know the context of your problem? For instance, perhaps you could edit to include the code to reproduce this error, or the links to previous questions that led you to where you are now.

Comment: The document you provided doesn't throw any error. Also the error you state in your question doesn't look like a normal (La)TeX error, are you sure that's exactly the error as you get it in the log?

Comment: Is your tex system up to date?

Comment: Hopefully no one suggested that you edit `pstricks.tex` You should never edit files in the distribution, if necessary you can redefine the command in your preamble but never edit the tex distribution files or you will just make your system incompatible with everyone elses. It's not possible to really help more unless you provide an example and show the error you get.

Comment: Thanks to all for helpful comments.  I am certain that my system is not current, and I will have to work on that.